# Google Chrome show artifacts on videos, webcam background and Google Earth on Linux

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, gpu

I have this issue that seems to have come out from nothing, yesterday everything was working fine

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom launcher:

```
google-chrome --use-gl=desktop
```